# Can't make jQuery rating plugin (Raty) work

Tags: javascript, jquery, raty

I'm trying to use [Raty - jQuery rating plugin](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/) on my website, but I just can't make it work.

Plugin is working but only on default settings:

```
  $.fn.raty.defaults = {
    cancel        : false,
    cancelHint    : 'Cancel this rating!',
    cancelOff     : 'cancel-off.png',
    cancelOn      : 'cancel-on.png',
    cancelPlace   : 'left',
    click         : undefined,
    half          : false,
    halfShow      : true,
    hints         : ['Beznadziejny', 'Słaby', 'Średni', 'Dobry', 'Bardzo dobry'],
    iconRange     : undefined,
    mouseout      : undefined,
    mouseover     : undefined,
    noRatedMsg    : 'Not rated yet!',
    number        : 5,
    numberMax     : 20,
    path          : '',
    precision     : false,
    readOnly      : false,
    round         : { down: .25, full: .6, up: .76 },
    score         : undefined,
    scoreName     : 'score',
    single        : false,
    size          : 16,
    space         : true,
    starHalf      : 'star-half.png',
    starOff       : 'star-off.png',
    starOn        : 'star-on.png',
    target        : undefined,
    targetFormat  : '{score}',
    targetKeep    : false,
    targetText    : '',
    targetType    : 'hint',
    width         : undefined
  };
```

when I'm trying to make my own setting directly to choose DIV it just doesn't work and use the default settings.

My div

```
<div id=\"score\" class=\"score\">
```

My #score

```
     $('#score').raty({
.. CODE FROM PREVIOUS PLUS
        score: 3,
        click: function(score, evt) {
        alert('ID: ' + this.id + "\nscore: " + score + "\nevent: " + evt);
    });



});
```

so I want to make in div with ID score: 3 but it doesn't work and I just get default setting. Of course all JS files are connected in HTML.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your FULL page source?

Comment: @MrBr1ghtSide Hmm it's too big code. That would be hard to put whole code and make it run on jsfiddle.

Comment: post only the relevant parts then(div html + javascript code)

Comment: @MrBr1ghtSide

http://jsfiddle.net/mp8c6fj0/  but it doesnt work on fiddle, hard to make work whole that code.

Comment: Is the missing '}' to close the 'click' function in your sample code missing in your production code as well?